# $ \{x\in X:h(x)\leq r\} $ is sequentially compact subset of $X$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, compactness

Let $(X,\|.\|)$ be a reflexive Banach space and $(D,\|.\|)$ be a Suslin subspace of $X$ such that $D$ is weakly closed subset of $X$.

Take $h:X\to [0,+\infty]$ such that $h(x)=\|x\|$ if $x\in D$ and $h(x)=+\infty$ otherwise.

Can we say that for all  $r\in\mathbb{R}$
$$
\{x\in X:h(x)\leq r\}
$$
is sequentially compact subset of $X$?

Comment: $\overline{B}(0,r)$ is weakly compact thus $\{x:h(x)\leq r\}$ is relatively weakly compact, it follows from Eberlein - Šmulian theorem that $\{x:h(x)\leq r\}$ is sequentially compact subset of $X$